# Balanced choice of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of strings that are 10 characters long.

```
final_list = ['ACTGCATGTC',
 'CAACACAACG',
 'TTCATGCCGA',
 'AGCCGTGTAT',
 'CAGTCACCAT',
 'TCGTACGTGC',
 'GAGATTGGTG',
 'GCATGTTCCA',
 ...]
```

[Full file](https://1drv.ms/t/s!Asb7WztvacfOucpSFpyG28shkxNOMQ)

I would like to pick 384 from the 1389 total strings, so that the A,C,G and T characters are as equally represented as possible:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

balance_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(final_list)

pos_dict = defaultdict()

for i in range(0, len(balance_df.columns)):
    pos_dict[i] = Counter(balance_df[i])

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pos_dict)
```

Ideally every letter should be represented 96 times at each position in the final 384 list.

```
      0 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
A   383 375 372 353 342 342 333 326 319 318
C   401 398 388 380 380 373 367 372 381 379
G   304 317 315 350 349 360 363 366 372 380
T   301 299 314 306 318 314 326 325 317 312
```

I attempted to do this by keeping track of accepted strings and then creating a list of the two most under represented characters and allowing only those to be added the next iteration:

```
from heapq import nsmallest

compliance_dict = defaultdict(dict)
for s in range(0,10):
#set up dict
    compliance_dict[s]['A'] = 0
    compliance_dict[s]['T'] = 0
    compliance_dict[s]['G'] = 0
    compliance_dict[s]['C'] = 0


def acceptable_balance(counts, str_to_add):

    allowed = defaultdict(list)
    for s in range(0,10):
        ratio_dict = defaultdict()
        total_row = sum(compliance_dict[s].values())
        if total_row == 0:
            allowed[s].extend(['A','T','C','G'])
        else:
            ratio_dict['A'] = compliance_dict[s].get('A')/total_row
            ratio_dict['T'] = compliance_dict[s].get('T')/total_row
            ratio_dict['G'] = compliance_dict[s].get('G')/total_row
            ratio_dict['C'] = compliance_dict[s].get('C')/total_row

        two_lowest = nsmallest(2,ratio_dict,key=lambda x: (ratio_dict.get(x),x))

        for al in two_lowest:
            allowed[s].append(al)

    reject = []
    for s in range(0,10):
        if str_to_add[s] in allowed[s]:
            reject.append(0)
        else:
            reject.append(1)

    if sum(reject) == 0:
        add = True
    else:
        add = False

    return add

def check_balance(count_dict, new_str):


    added = False

    if acceptable_balance(count_dict, new_str):
        for s in range(0,len(new_str)):

            #add count
            count_dict[s][new_str[s]] += 1

        added = True

    return added
```

Comment: I know it's been a few days, but in case you're interested I've made some improvements to the code so it can run faster and I came up with an additional approach that guarantees better solutions faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there are 1.07e354 combinations, so brute forcing them is impossible.

Any algorithm which depends on making future decisions based on what strings have been accepted so far is liable to be stuck in a local extremum. For example, what if the next string fits your criteria, but if you were to reject it and wait for the one after it, you'd get a perfect solution? And if you accept the next one, which you will do, the one after it may now be rejected anyway. In the worst case, based on your choices so far no available string will be good anymore and you won't be able to reach a solution.

Your method is very inflexible, because you'll reject any string that doesn't have one of the two most under represented bases for each position. You can't even reach a solution unless you have a pretty low tolerance, e.g., allow a string as long as half of its bases are from the two most under represented for each position. And even then the solution will be very suboptimal.

### Solution

I propose an iterative metric minimisation approach. You choose any 384 strings and you leave the rest in a "pool". For each string in your chosen list, you substitute it with each one in the pool and measure whether this improves your metric. If it does, you make the switch. After you have gone through all 384 strings, if your metric has improved, you can begin the process again, else you have converged to a solution.

We can represent each string as a 4x10 table like the one in your question, with 1s in the appropriate places and 0 everywhere else. In fact, it's slightly more efficient if we have a flat array with 40 elements, but the idea is the same. After we sum all 384 such arrays, we get the equivalent of your pandas table. Since the mean is 96 by definition and you want as many elements as possible to be as close to 96 as possible, the standard deviation (SD) is the perfect metric.

```
import numpy as np

def decompose_strings(strings):
    decomposition = np.zeros((len(strings), 40,))
    strides = dict(zip('ATCG', range(4)))
    for i, string in enumerate(strings):
        for j, value in enumerate(string):
            decomposition[i,10 * strides[value] + j] = 1
    return decomposition

def minimise_variance(table, size):
    idx = list(np.random.choice(range(table.shape[0]), size, replace=False))
    chosen = idx
    pool = [i for i in range(table.shape[0]) if i not in idx]

    print('{0:>10s}{1:>10s}'.format('start', 'end'))
    print('-' * 20)
    std = table[chosen].sum(axis=0).std()
    while True:
        start_std = std
        for i, chosen_idx in enumerate(chosen):
            # for each `i`, the remaining `size` - 1 elements will sum up
            # to the same costant, so we should only calculate it once
            temp_sum = table[chosen].sum(axis=0) - table[chosen_idx]
            j_better = None
            for j, pool_idx in enumerate(pool):
                current_std = (temp_sum + table[pool_idx]).std()
                if current_std < std:
                    std = current_std
                    j_better = j
            if j_better is not None:
                chosen[i] = pool[j_better]
                pool[j_better] = chosen_idx
            else:
                chosen[i] = chosen_idx
        print('{0:10.6f}{1:10.6f}'.format(start_std, std))
        if start_std == std:
            break
    return chosen
```

And to run it

```
with open('final_list.txt') as f:
    data = f.read().split('\n')[:-1]
table = decompose_strings(data)

solution = minimise_variance(table, 384)
```

On average, a solution converges in 4 iterations, with each iteration taking 15 seconds on my machine.

Every solution will have a lot of table values with 96 and a few will be 95 or 97. In fact, each 95 will be paired with a 97, so that the mean can be 96. This means that the number of errors will always be an even number and in this case we can even calculate the SD with `np.sqrt(errors / 40)`.

I collected the results from 200 runs and plotted a histogram of the number of errors (inversed the formula above to compute it from the SD).

[image]

### EDIT

We can do better than that if we chain the solutions. We call the function again and ask it to start with the previously returned solution, but we swap one element for a new one and then let it converge. While it is true that by swapping a random element in we increase the SD and the new solution may even have a higher SD than the previous one, the SD seems to generally be confined in the 10-14 error range. Not only that, but it is very likely the new function call will converge within 2 iterations; one to find something new and one to confirm that there is nothing better.

```
# just change this
def minimise_variance(table, size):
    idx = list(np.random.choice(range(table.shape[0]), size, replace=False))

# to this
def minimise_variance(table, size, idx=None):
    if not idx:
        idx = list(np.random.choice(range(table.shape[0]), size, replace=False))
    else:
        idx = list(idx)
        # By shuffling the indices we ensure there is no bias
        # in which element is rotated out and which ones are
        # considered first for improvement.
        np.random.shuffle(idx)
        while True:
            switch_idx = np.random.choice(range(table.shape[0]))
            if switch_idx not in idx:
                # if we were to switch out the first element, it's likely
                # the old solution could be found again
                idx[-1] = switch_idx
                break
```

And run it like so

```
solutions = [minimise_variance(table, 384)]
for _ in range(1, 10):
    solutions.append(minimise_variance(table, 384, solutions[-1]))
```

I wrote a C version of this code and collected 100k runs.

[image]

There were 22 solutions with 4 errors, all fairly unique with one another.

The sorted indices of one of them were

```
[3, 11, 28, 121, 123, 125, 132, 263, 264, 272, 292, 307, 314, 319, 334, 341, 350, 355, 365, 366, 371, 388, 390, 399, 401, 404, 425, 434, 441, 449, 458, 459, 474, 475, 480, 484, 485, 486, 487, 488, 489, 490, 496, 498, 499, 500, 501, 502, 504, 505, 507, 508, 512, 516, 517, 518, 519, 523, 525, 530, 534, 535, 540, 541, 544, 546, 548, 549, 551, 552, 555, 557, 558, 559, 560, 562, 563, 564, 566, 567, 569, 570, 572, 573, 574, 575, 576, 577, 578, 579, 580, 581, 582, 583, 584, 586, 587, 589, 591, 593, 600, 611, 633, 643, 647, 655, 658, 659, 665, 667, 668, 669, 672, 674, 679, 680, 683, 686, 693, 697, 715, 718, 720, 723, 724, 725, 729, 732, 735, 736, 737, 741, 742, 749, 751, 753, 755, 758, 760, 764, 765, 766, 767, 771, 772, 773, 775, 779, 780, 782, 783, 786, 787, 789, 790, 791, 798, 801, 806, 807, 808, 810, 811, 814, 816, 817, 820, 822, 823, 825, 826, 827, 830, 831, 832, 834, 835, 836, 840, 843, 845, 846, 847, 849, 850, 853, 855, 858, 867, 871, 874, 884, 887, 889, 897, 900, 905, 912, 915, 918, 941, 946, 956, 958, 959, 966, 971, 975, 976, 980, 984, 986, 988, 990, 991, 996, 999, 1001, 1003, 1011, 1013, 1015, 1016, 1017, 1018, 1020, 1028, 1029, 1032, 1036, 1037, 1038, 1039, 1041, 1042, 1045, 1046, 1047, 1048, 1049, 1050, 1055, 1057, 1058, 1059, 1060, 1061, 1062, 1063, 1064, 1065, 1066, 1067, 1069, 1071, 1072, 1074, 1075, 1076, 1077, 1078, 1080, 1083, 1084, 1085, 1087, 1089, 1091, 1093, 1095, 1098, 1099, 1103, 1107, 1109, 1110, 1113, 1118, 1119, 1124, 1125, 1126, 1127, 1128, 1130, 1133, 1135, 1136, 1138, 1140, 1141, 1142, 1145, 1146, 1149, 1150, 1152, 1153, 1154, 1156, 1157, 1158, 1159, 1160, 1161, 1162, 1163, 1164, 1165, 1166, 1167, 1169, 1170, 1171, 1173, 1175, 1176, 1178, 1179, 1180, 1181, 1182, 1183, 1184, 1185, 1187, 1188, 1189, 1190, 1191, 1192, 1194, 1196, 1198, 1199, 1201, 1203, 1204, 1205, 1206, 1207, 1208, 1209, 1210, 1211, 1212, 1213, 1214, 1217, 1218, 1220, 1221, 1222, 1223, 1224, 1225, 1226, 1227, 1230, 1231, 1233, 1234, 1235, 1236, 1240, 1241, 1242, 1243, 1246, 1247, 1250, 1255, 1257, 1258, 1259, 1260, 1262, 1265, 1266, 1267, 1268, 1276, 1279, 1321]
```

And its pandas table

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
A  96  96  96  96  96  96  96  96  96  96
C  97  96  96  96  96  96  96  96  96  96
G  96  96  96  96  96  97  96  96  96  96
T  95  96  96  96  96  95  96  96  96  96
```